# find the highest and lowest number in array with JOptionPane [Closeed]

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, joptionpane

the code it's for education in college
I need the user to insert a values of array and find which number is the highest and lowest but the lowest number doesn't work . 
can anyone explain this to me , sorry for asking much

```
int m=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter index"));       
int values;
int num [] = new int [m];

int max = num[0];
int min = num[0];
for (int i=0;i<num.length;i++)      
     {                          
     num[i] = values =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value"));   
     System.out.println(num[i]);

     if (num[i] > max)
     {
         max=num[i];
     }
     if (num[i] < min )
     {
         min=num[i];
     }

}                                    
System.out.println("Largest Number in a given array is : " + max);
System.out.println("Smallest Number in a given array is : " + min);
```

Comment: `num[i] = values =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value")); ` why do you have `values` in between.

Comment: There is quite a lot wrong with this code. You need to learn basics of if then else control flow https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html.  If something is X and is greater than Y it cant also be less than Y or equal to Y.  Also you are looking to sort a collection which can be done using collections.

Comment: why is "index" defining the size of the array??

Comment: first, read the elements, only then loop over the array to compare them. at this point, if all your numbers are negative, you would (falsely) get 0 as max value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.sort()` to sort the array and simply access the first(0th) index which will hold the smallest number, and the last index which will hold the largest number:

```
int m=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter index"));       
 //int values; dont need this
 int num [] = new int [m]; //num is initialised with length entered by the user

 //int max = num[0]; no need
 //int min = num[0]; no need
 for (int i=0;i<num.length;i++)      
 {                          
  num[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value"));   
  System.out.println(num[i]);      

 }
Arrays.sort(num); //this will sort your array in ascending order: smallest number will be at the 0th index and largest will be at the last index                                    
System.out.println("Largest Number in a given array is : " + num[num.length-1]);
System.out.println("Smallest Number in a given array is : " + num[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,

```
int[] num= new int[4];
```

After initialize num, num will be {0, 0, 0, 0};

```
int max = num[0];
int min = num[0];
```

So now min will be 0, because num[0] is 0 - no matter what you enter.

```
num[i] = values =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value"));   
System.out.println(num[i]);
if(i == 0)
      min = num[i];
```

Try this and think about it (same for max value)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code - so using your attempt, you can set the first value *after* it's been received from the user as the min and max, and work from there:

```
int m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter index"));
int num[] = new int[m];
int max = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value"));
System.out.println(max);
int min = max;
for (int i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i++) {
    num[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value"));
    System.out.println(num[i]);
    if (num[i] > max) {
        max = num[i];
    } else if (num[i] < min) {
        min = num[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("Largest Number in a given array is : " + max);
System.out.println("Smallest Number in a given array is : " + min);
```

---

With 5 inputs of 3, 8, 6, 4 and -33, the output is:

> Largest Number in a given array is : 8
>
> Smallest Number in a given array is : -33

---

Just for fun, here's an alternative solution that's quite inefficient:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(num).boxed().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max().getAsInt());
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(num).boxed().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).min().getAsInt());
```

Or of course you could sort the array with [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)) and then find the max with `array[array.length() - 1]` and the min with `array[0]`

Comment: He wants to show the input dialog for x number of times based on the first input (after user enters the index) to get user's input and put them in the array. Your code asking for input 1 extra time, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @darkPain it does - that's why I put `i < num.length - 1` in the loop.

Comment: aghh I see, my bad sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`  and `Integer_MIN_VALUE`. max value for an integer is 2147483647(2^31-1) and min value for an integer is -2147483648(-2^31)

```
int m=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter index"));       
int num [] = new int [m];
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

 for (int i=0;i<num.length;i++)      
 {                          
     num[i] = values =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value"));   
     System.out.println(num[i]);
     if (num[i] > max)
     {
         max=num[i];
     }
     if (num[i] < min )
     {
         min=num[i];
     }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Yes, that's the best solution, but the point is to do it without an inbuilt function.